# Is there a way to index all contracts which deployed in an EVM-based chain?

Tags: solidity, abi

I don't want to use a third party explorer or database, **please don't give examples such as etherscan, 4byte directory etc.**

**This is basically what i want to do:**

basically I need the ABIs of the contracts. Why do I need this?
I learned that I would need ABIs to decode input/topics in txs.(this is my main purpose)

**So, I guess i need:**

- Index all contract addresses
- Get ABIs of these contracts

I believe there is someone out there who can guide me in the right direction, please help.

Comment: It is doable. Just download the blockchain, start parsing transaction, tracing contract execution, etc. Perhaps, the biggest issue is that contract's ABI aren't part of the blockchain. You could identify well known contracts, like AMM, Tokens, etc, but without external help you won't be able to interpret all the contracts.

Comment: unfortunately you won't make it without Etherscan, Etherscan has became a public space which concentrates the sources of major contracts and the only way to get the ABI is to download it from there. Otherwise, learn EVM assembly and disassemble yourself, to derive the ABI

Comment: and btw, Etherscan actuall has a decompiler which is quiet good, it has signatures of all the methods from Ethereum Signature Database, so it names the functions like in the original contract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your question very carefully and understand what you need.

Well, the Ethereum node contains the smart contract code and its data, but does not contain the smart contract code. And you can only get the ABI from the smart contract code. Which means you can get the ABI for only verified contract.

So you should get the contract which is verified first.
Then, where can you get the verified contract?
Since etherescan.io is launched, most of the users verify their contract on it so nowadays, Etherscan has most(I think all) verified contract's code and you can get the ABI from there.

So I think it is impossible to get the ABI without using Etherscan.
But if you can use Eetherscan, I can help you.

I am not sure why you need to index all contract addresses.
But you can use Etherscan API to get the ABI for the verified smart contract.
And the API is free.

So please enjoy it.
Thanks

Comment: Actually, the reason why I don't want to use etherscan is this: I think that there may be some internal methods in the EVM compatible chain which I mentioned. If I could speak with you via DM, I'd like to explain exactly why we need this, but that just doesn't seem possible. We were looking to hire a developer or mentor who could help with that (for a fee ofc), I would like to explain exactly what we needed and maybe we could see what we actually needed or not.

Comment: The chain in question is: An EVM-compatible chain using the Cosmos sdk. And in this chain, besides cosmos type Tx hashes, there are also Ethereum type hashes.
In order to be able to decode the results of these hashes correctly, as a result of my research, I found that I would need the ABIs of the contracts.

Also, I don't think there is a way to get the contracts deployed on this chain with the etherscan API.

Comment: If you do not use Ethereum chain, then Etherscan API will not work for you.
Please leave your tg name here.
I also know about cosmos SDK, so I can help you.